# IIS 10 Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-server-2016, .net-3.5

I've a web site that show 'Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))' in Windows Server 2016. The issue only appeared when ASP.NET was initializing on the first request from a web browser. If you requested the website a second time, the application would finally start.

Try the options:

- The website configure the application pool in compatibility with
  32-bits.
- The folder list add group users 'IIS_IUSRS' in security.
- Register framework with aspnet_regiis.
- Register User application pool (aspnet_regiis -ga).
- Reinstall windows feature 'Web-AppInit'

Any other suggestions to correct it?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))

Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 
[COMException (0x8000ffff): Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))]

[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.JScript, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle._GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName) +0
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +64
   System.RuntimeType.PrivateGetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +58
   System.Type.GetType(String typeName) +50
   System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerInfo.get_IsCodeDomProviderTypeValid() +9
   System.Web.Compilation.CompilationUtil.GetRecompilationHash(CompilationSection ps) +2487
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.get_RecompilationHash() +99
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CheckTopLevelFilesUpToDate2(StandardDiskBuildResultCache diskCache) +388
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CheckTopLevelFilesUpToDate(StandardDiskBuildResultCache diskCache) +55
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PrecompiledAppRuntimeModeInitialize() +220
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.Initialize() +9020121
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InitializeBuildManager() +267
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags) +224

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.JScript, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +8997667
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +85
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +333


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.8745; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.8745
```

Comment: I think you are using .NET version 2.0 - is that the version you want to use? If not, change it in the AppPool ...

Comment: The Application pool configure .NET CLR version v2.0.50727 and the web site Framework 3.5